# Convert simple date into SQLite datetime format?

Tags: date, sqlite

I have date in new Date() format. I need to convert to SQLite date time format.(2014-01-05T00:00:00.000Z). Is it possible to do so??

```
var  date = new Date();
```

now I need to convert this date to SQLite datetime format like (2014-01-05T00:00:00.000Z).

Comment: It'd be helpful if you mentioned WHICH language this `new Date()` is coming from...

Comment: By and large you should not have to think about the sqlite string format for dates.  Your database adapter should convert the canonical date object in your programming language to the correct format automatically, without making you do a string conversion explicitly at all.  However, as noted above, we need to know what programming language you are using to give more specific advice =)

Comment: it is coming in simple java script.

Comment: i have it in simple javascript format. Now i need to convert into the sqlite date time format. like 2014-01-05T00:00:00.000Z

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_toisostring.asp

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use this

```
// Create an instance of the Date class
var date = new Date();

// Convert it to an ISO string
var sqliteDate = Date.toISOString();
```

take a look at this [W3schools](http://w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_toisostring.asp)

Comment: Why is this one downvoted and the one below it is the same, but voted well?

Comment: @MichaelSacks - I guess because the original answer didn't have any code (just the link). The code was added 5 months after the other answer.

Comment: Because it uses Date as a variable which is protected name, it's would basically override Date class..

Answer (score 15):

Try:

```
var date = new Date();
var sqllite_date = date.toISOString();
```

Comment: Best way found to get compatibility between sqlite DATETIME format and javascript Date object. With this method, date method on sqlite work similessly and javascript understand new Date(sqllite_date).

Comment: Need to handle the timezone too

Answer (score -2):

You can use strftime, from [date and time functions](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html).

```
SELECT strftime('%d-%m-%Y', 'now')
```

Output

```
10-06-2010
```

Hope this helps ..:)

Comment: This doesn't answer the question at all. It's not in Javascript and the result is not an ISO 8601 string.